# Filemanagers crash all the time

Tags: nautilus, lubuntu, filemanager, segmentation-fault, pcmanfm

I'm using Lubuntu 12.04 and having problems with the filemanager. When I try to open the filemanager nothing happens. In the dmesg log the following error is shown:
`pcmanfm[2330]: segfault at 10 ip xxxxx sp xxxxx error 4 in libgioremote-volume-monitor.so[xxxxx+10000]`

The filemanagers Thunar and Nautilus show the same errors. 
Has anyone seen this problem before? Is there a solution where I don't need to reinstall lubuntu?

Comment: Try a full system upgrade: `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I already did that, but it didn't help. Still the same issue.